# How to wipe Heroku Redis?

Tags: heroku, redis

I have some information stored in my RedisToGo instance in Heroku and I want to wipe it so the Redis store is clean. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Yes I want to clear the entire store.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can do this with **redis-cli**.

RedisToGo gives you a url in the form:

```
redis://redistogo:d20739cffb0c0a6fff719acc2728c236@catfish.redistogo.com:9402
```

So this command will empty your db:

```
redis-cli -h catfish.redistogo.com -p 9402 -a d20739cffb0c0a6fff719acc2728c236 flushall
```

Comment: This gives me `(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.`. What is that about?

Comment: @torazaburo That error occurs when you've entered bad credentials.

Comment: This no longer works. You get a NOAUTH error. There may be a missing step, but the steps above will just yield an error.

Comment: @JesseFarmer I was just able to run this command successfully. Received "OK" response. You might want to double check your credentials.

Comment: @ty, it responds with OK, but it seems like it doesn't actually clear it. So far I wasn't able to find a way to clear rediscloud redis without accessing rails console.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, you can simply do `redis-cli -u redis://...` with the URL

Answer (score 54):

You can install the **heroku-redis-cli** plugin

### Installation

*Requirements:*

- The heroku gem — `gem install heroku`
- A local installation of redis (or at least the redis-cli utility) — `apt-get install redis-server`

*To install:*

- `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/rapportive-oss/heroku-redis-cli.git`

### Usage

- `heroku redis:info` — get run-time statistics from your redis.
- `heroku redis:monitor` — monitor commands being sent to your redis in real time.
- `heroku redis:cli` — execute custom commands against redis.

Then you could simply do:

```sh
$ heroku redis:cli
$ flushall
```

Steps taken from *readme* file on the github repo: https://github.com/rapportive-oss/heroku-redis-cli

Comment: It is not an _Heroku_ command but an [heroku-redis-cli](https://github.com/rapportive-oss/heroku-redis-cli) plugin command.

Comment: It hasn't been updated for over 2 years and doesn't work

Comment: this was definitely an easier approach.  worked for me.

Comment: The plugin fails to install.

Answer (score 37):

To wipe your redis on heroku there are a couple of ways. One of the simplest is probably connecting to the heroku console and clearing it from there.
Commands are (for cedar stack):

```
heroku run console
REDIS.flushall
```

And that's it :-)

Comment: only if you are running a ruby app

Answer (score 25):

You can do this with the heroku console:

```
$ heroku redis:cli -a my_app --confirm my_app
$ FLUSHALL
```

Source: https://menubar.io/heroku-redis-flushall

Comment: @Keyul just tried it and it seems to still be working.

Answer (score 13):

You can destroy and recreate the entire Redis datastore for your app by doing:

```
heroku addons:remove redistogo
heroku addons:add redistogo
```

Comment: Is there a better way than dropping and re-adding the whole instance?

Comment: That's the easiest way.  If you are using the environment variable then this should be a quick and easy change.

Answer (score 11):

In order to empty the store, you can run the flushall command: http://redis.io/commands/flushall

So, simply something like:

```
$redis.flushall
```

if you're doing it with Ruby or similar.

Comment: It depends on what you're using to be honest, if it's something like Rails you can run it via the Rails console (`heroku run console`) - however, it's very dependant on what tools you're using.

Answer (score 9):

Get a python shell on heroku by doing the following CLI:

```
heroku run python
```

Then in that shell type

```
import os
import redis
redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost')
r = redis.from_url(redis_url) 
r.flushdb()
```

Answer (score 3):

`heroku run rails c`

`$redis.flushall`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ruby on Rails on Heroku and tried this, it worked (After `heroku run rails console`)

```
> $redis = Redis.new url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']
> $redis.flushall
=> "OK"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this https://github.com/rapportive-oss/heroku-redis-cli to connect to the Redis instance you are using, Heroku update broke it some time ago but there is a fix https://github.com/johnbeynon/heroku-redis-cli. Then just do `flushdb`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one convenient one-liner, even for non-ruby apps:

```sh
echo " FLUSHALL\r\n QUIT" | heroku redis:cli -a MY_APP --confirm MY_APP
```

Replace `MY_APP` with the name of your app.

---

*Note: This assumes that you have [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed.*

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a one-liner (and happen to be using Rails), you can do

```
heroku run rails runner 'REDIS.flushall'
```

rather than connecting first (with console) then manually entering the `flushall` command.