# How do i do a Heroku Jawsdb InnoDB database restore?

Tags: mysql, database, heroku

I am a hobbyist.

Basically i'm playing with a heroku app-->php--> wordpress multisite-->JawsDB with innoDB/mysql.

I didn't realise that the free database limit is only 5MB. (yes i know, i've upgraded my plan already, but its too late now.) I sort of pushed the limits, then after a while, i couldn't append new tables or add new information. Then the next thing i knew, the database crashed.

And then i have a nice generic "Error establishing a database connection".

Luckily i was using autobus to automatically keep a backup of the database, which i managed to download to a xyz.sql file.

But the question is how should i restore the database file? I.e upload my local sql file to the SQL server?

I am able to connect via heidiSQL, but i would have to change line by line...

Is there a proper way to do this? I'm getting quite desperate already...

I've tried $mysql -u -p -h database < file 
doesnt seem to work...

I know i should've learnt more computer science before trying this... but any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noob question above.

Ok the command

$mysql -h [host]-P [port] -u [username] -p[password] [table] < [file of dump].sql

Yes, it worked, but the -p and the [password] column *cannot* have a space.

Also when working on heroku, have to flush the redis cache... can follow the below link.

[How to wipe Heroku Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137500/how-to-wipe-heroku-redis)